# changing comma in csv to semicolon

Tags: python, csv

('Radial Velocity', {'number': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 'orbital_period':

This is my sample output with code:

```
def parse_planets_file(file):    
with open('exoplanets.csv', 'r') as file:   #opening source file as read type
    data = file.readlines()
output = {}      # prepare output dictionary
for element, line in enumerate(data, 0):           # read line by line       
    items = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')      # split columns       
    if element == 0:                               # formatting inner dictionary's keys in a list: 'number', orbital_period', 'mass', 'distance', 'year'
        values = [key for key in items[1:]]
    else:

        if items[0] not in output.keys():           # add main key to the output dictionary: 'Radial Velocity', 'Imaging', 'Transit'
            output[items[0]] = {key : [] for key in values}
        for value, key in enumerate(values, 1):                  # add value to the inner dictionary
            if items[value] != '':                               # if the value is a valid number ( not a string) , convert it to float
                output[items[0]][key].append(float(items[value]))
for items in output.items():
    return (items)
```

print(parse_planets_file(file))

Comment: How do I add a semicolon following Radial velocity instead of comma

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you are using

Answer (score 0):

If your input is this tuple for example:

tp = ('Radial Velocity', {'number': [
      1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0], 'orbital_period': [
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0]})

```
dict_example = dict(tp[1]) 
# Converts the second part of the tuple ({'number'....}) structure to a dictionary. 
# Which in turn infers the types of the objects in the lists.

for key, value in dict_example.items():
    print(key, value)
    print(type(value[0]))
```

Example output:

```
number [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0]
<class 'float'>
orbital_period [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0]
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: that's my output however, i want the comma following velocity to be a semicolon in my output

Comment: 'Radial Velocity', <- this comma?

Comment: You could grab the outer features initially and make a nested dictionary, check out these references:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary ,
https://overlaid.net/2016/02/04/convert-a-csv-to-a-dictionary-in-python/

Comment: You could also just load it in with pandas:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html,
which will assume the structure.